# /lib/modules/.../build: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, makefile, kali-linux

Пытался установить драйвера по [инструкции](https://static.tp-link.com/Installation%20for%20linux%20driver_RTL.pdf) для сетевого адаптера *TP-Link Archer T1U* скачанные с официального [сайта](https://www.tp-link.com/ru/download/Archer-T1U_V1.html#Driver) TP-Link'a и словил ошибку:

```
root@kali:~/Desktop/Archer_T1U_V1_150909/Driver# make
make -C UTIL/ osutil
make[1]: Entering directory '/root/Desktop/Archer_T1U_V1_150909/Driver/UTIL'
cp -f os/linux/Makefile.6.util /root/Desktop/Archer_T1U_V1_150909/Driver/UTIL/os/linux/Makefile
make -C /lib/modules/4.14.0-kali3-amd64/build SUBDIRS=/root/Desktop/Archer_T1U_V1_150909/Driver/UTIL/os/linux modules
make[2]: Entering directory '/root/Desktop/Archer_T1U_V1_150909/Driver/UTIL'
make[2]: *** /lib/modules/4.14.0-kali3-amd64/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/root/Desktop/Archer_T1U_V1_150909/Driver/UTIL'
Makefile:527: recipe for target 'osutil' failed
make[1]: *** [osutil] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/Desktop/Archer_T1U_V1_150909/Driver/UTIL'
Makefile:3: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Ну и make install:

```
root@kali:~/Desktop/Archer_T1U_V1_150909/Driver# make install
make -C UTIL/ install_util
make[1]: Entering directory '/root/Desktop/Archer_T1U_V1_150909/Driver/UTIL'
make -C /root/Desktop/Archer_T1U_V1_150909/Driver/UTIL/os/linux -f Makefile.6.util install
make[2]: Entering directory '/root/Desktop/Archer_T1U_V1_150909/Driver/UTIL/os/linux'
install -d /lib/modules/4.14.0-kali3-amd64/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/
install -m 644 -c mt7650u_sta_util.ko /lib/modules/4.14.0-kali3-amd64/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/
install: cannot stat 'mt7650u_sta_util.ko': No such file or directory
Makefile.6.util:50: recipe for target 'install' failed
make[2]: *** [install] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/root/Desktop/Archer_T1U_V1_150909/Driver/UTIL/os/linux'
Makefile:490: recipe for target 'install_util' failed
make[1]: *** [install_util] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/Desktop/Archer_T1U_V1_150909/Driver/UTIL'
Makefile:16: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

Версия ядра:

```
root@kali:~/Desktop/Archer_T1U_V1_150909/Driver# uname -a
Linux kali 4.14.0-kali3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.14.12-2kali1 (2018-01-08) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Прежде чем продолжить, ты точно **уверен**, что тебе **необходимо** собирать модуль? По проблеме: linux-headers установлены?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> /lib/modules/.../build: No such file or directory

не установлены заголовочные файл программы *linux*. в debian-основных дистрибутивах установить пакет с ними (для работающей в данный момент версии программы *linux*) можно, например, так:

```
$ sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

---

объяснение: для сборки модулей для программы *linux* нужны заголовочные файлы **именно к той версии программы**, в которую вы этот модуль собираетесь загружать. уточняйте у того, кто собирал вам программу *linux*, где взять заголовочные файлы именно к этой версии.

если получите их в виде каталога, то надо самому сделать символическую ссылку `build` на этот каталог (именно её и не хватает вам для сборки):

```
$ sudo ln -s /путь/к/заголовочным/файлам/ /lib/modules/<версия>/build
```

Comment: При установке данной командой, получаю ошибку: E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.14.0-kali3-amd64
Вычитал, что стоит воспользоваться командой apt-cache search linux-headers и установить альтернативу. Но в этом случае make по прежнему обращается к /lib/modules/4.14.0-kali3-amd64/build и разумеется выдает ошибку

Comment: разжевал в тексте ответа.